# How to create dictionary from common elements in a string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, for-loop

I need to put all the seconds character from a string that have the same first character in common.

This is my code:

```py
Coin_Info = Binance_Client.get_all_coins_info()
for n in Coin_Info:
    Coin, Net = n['coin'], n['networkList']
    for e in Net:
        if e['depositEnable'] and e['withdrawEnable'] is True:
            print(Coin, e['network'])
```

output:

```py
GALA BSC
GALA ETH
VIB ETH
FIS BSC
FIS ETH
BAR CHZ
RAD ETH
COTI BSC
COTI BNB
COTI ETH
```

but i need to transform it in a dictionary like this:

```
GALA = {'BSC', 'ETH'}
VIB = {'ETH'}
FIS = {'BSC', 'ETH'}
BAR = {'CHZ'}
RAD = {'ETH'}
COTI = {'BSC', 'BNB', 'ETH'}
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {}
Coin_Info = Binance_Client.get_all_coins_info()
for n in Coin_Info:
    Coin, Net = n['coin'], n['networkList']
    for e in Net:
        if e['depositEnable'] and e['withdrawEnable']:
            if not my_dict.hasKey(Coin):
                my_dict[Coin] = []
            my_dict[Coin].append(e['network'])
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it is working :) but in python3 hasKey in replaced with ____contains____